# SVN/TRAC Post Commit hook error

Tags: linux, svn, unix, trac, post-commit

I am new (and currently learning how) to managing SVN and Trac.  We have a ticketing system setup so users will be required to leave comments for each commit that, at a minimum, require a ticket reference number.  Everything seems to be working with the exception of the user receiving a post commit hook error that looks like the following:

[image]

I've been fumbling around with the post-commit hook script in SVN but haven't had much luck so far.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appeared as an issue after changes in Trac - I found related [issue](http://trac-hacks.org/ticket/8617)*. It was found that **repository_dir** in *trac.ini* was empty which caused that error.

> Trac 12 changed how repositories are setup, allowing multiple repos
>   for a single trac instance. The repository_dir key is no longer the
>   only way to configure a repository in trac, but that had previously
>   been "the way" that this was configured.

- used google cache to retrieve the page

Comment: Thanks.  I had actually came across this resource earlier today and, although I didn't have much luck to begin with, this absolutely fixed it.  I still don't entirely understand if this fix is going to allow for us to have multiple repos or not but thanks for your help and taking the time to look into this.